# shaping a signal using another signal

Tags: matlab, trigonometry

Greetings All 
I have a signal labeled 1) and I have another triangle signal labeled 
2) that I would like to have it molded to (I don't want to filter the 
signal just mold it to fit within the triangle shape). Does anyone 
know the best way to do this? Do I just multiply / add the signals 
together? 
here's the image link below 
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6576402/Diagram1.jpg 
tia 
sal22

Here's some matlab/octave code I've tried like @mor22 suggested I post
as you can see I tried a bunch of different y3 to see what happens.

```
%wave shapping
clear all
fs=1000; %sample frequence should be 44100 for cd quality

x=linspace(0,2*pi,fs);
y=sin(4*x);

%f3=max(min(f1,abs(f2)),-abs(f2))
y2=1*asin(sin (x+pi/2)); %arcsin creates comples number
y2=y2/abs(max(y2)); %make sure y2 is 1 or under 1
%y3=max(min(y,abs(y2)),-abs(y2));
%y3=y2.*y
y3=y2+y;
y3=y3/abs(max(y3)); %make sure y3 is 1 or under 1
plot(x,y,'g',x,y2,'r-',x,y3,'b*');
```

and a link to the image of the plot
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6576402/questions/Screenshot.png

The Green is the original signal.
The Red sawtooth wave is the envelope I want it to follow/be bounded by.
The blue is the final wave I'm having problems with

An example of what I'm trying to do with out the animation of course I just want the signal to be bounded like this, but bounded using a sawtooth wave I added the link below because I can only post one link as a new user
ocw.mit.edu/courses/mechanical-engineering/2-062j-wave-propagation-fall-2006/simulations/group_velocity/grpvel.gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a homework question, so I'll only lead you to the water. To understand signal shaping, just think of the function `sinc(x)=sin(x)/x`. This can be seen as a `sin(x)` shaped by the decay of a `1/x`.

The figure below shows the `sinc(x)` curve in blue and `± 1/x` in red. You can see that the zeros of the `sinc(x)` function are exactly the same as that of the underlying `sin(x)` function, i.e., `nπ`. The decay of the `1/x` shapes the `sin(x)` which results in the blue curve.

[image]

You can now infer from the definition of `sinc(x)` above, whether you have to multiply the two functions or add them. If you do the same with `sin(x)` and `abs(x)`, you get something like this

[image]

If I misinterpreted your question and you indeed wanted to just attach the end points of the `sine` like curve to the end points of the `abs(x)` like curve, then that's not shaping. You probably just need to translate the entire curve such that the end points for both coincide.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear but this animation may give a better explanation.  As you can see a sine wave signal is bounded by an envelop. 

[link]http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mechanical-engineering/2-062j-wave-propagation-fall-2006/simulations/group_velocity/grpvel.gif


 I'm trying to have my envelop be a saw tooth type of wave like this 

[link]http://planetmath.org/encyclopedia/SawBladeFunction.html

Comment: @Rick: You should multiply the two signals, not add. So uncomment the 4th line from the end and comment the one after it. The reason why your plots don't align is because you're renormalizing it repeatedly. Uncomment the second line from the end and you'll see that your `sin` wave is bounded by the sawtooth wave. To see it being bound neatly, use `plot(x,y2,'r',x,-y2,'r',x,y3,'b')`